# Is there any way to know the bytes which were processed by query jobs per reference table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to know how to calculate the total bytes which were processed by query jobs in a specified period per reference table to reduce BigQuery costs.

I can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA to know the reference table and bytes processed for each query, but I don't know how to directly calculate the processed bytes per table.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate how much bytes will be used for query?

Comment: My goal is to extract tables that have a large scan size due to the query.  
For example, the following query gives me the total scan size per query, but not per each reference table.  ```SELECT
  user_email,
  query,
  referenced_tables,
  total_bytes_processed
FROM
  `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
WHERE
  DATE(creation_time) >= '2022-05-01'
ORDER BY 4 DESC
LIMIT 30```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this, see the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dry-run-queries#perform_dry_runs) for more details but below is a summary:

1. From the UI just add the query and it will calculate the expected consumption.
   [image]
2. Alternatively, you can issue a bq command with the `--dry_run` flag like this:

```
bq query \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
--dry_run \
'SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.311_service_requests`;'
```

It will return the following message:
`Query successfully validated. Assuming the tables are not modified, running this query will process 259261 bytes of data.`

Unfortunately you will not be able to apply a general statement to each table individually as each query will have different usage of the data itself, the partitions, clusters, etc.

Comment: I would like to know is how to aggregate the scan size processed by already executed queries per reference table.   

> Unfortunately you will not be able to apply a general statement to each table individually as each query will have different usage of the data itself, the partitions, clusters, etc.  

Does this mean that there is no way to know the scan size per reference table?